# UIButton greys out when another View Controller is presented modally

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a few buttons in a View Controller. One of them performs a segue to another View Controller. When this happens, all buttons change tint color to grey. When VC is dismissed, everything comes back to normal colors. It happens fast but noticeable. I assume it has something to do with isHighlithed state. If you slowly slide down or hold VC when dismissing, you can clearly see that. It does make UI look weird.

How to prevent every single button from being greyed out?

Setting tint color to all buttons did not help.

Comment: It will be useful if you put some code or screenshot.

Comment: If you are presenting the second view controller modally (rather than as a push on a navigation stack), then what you describe sounds like the default behaviour for tint adjustment that was introduced in iOS 7.

Comment: It's `tintAdjustmentMode`, set it to `normal`